# Variation of secretary problem using groups growth

Tags: algorithm, optimization, probability, linear-programming

I am doing an essay on optimal stopping theory for college, particularly Probability subject. And I am struggling to write it because the books I find are too hard to understand for me (martingales, stochastic processes, Wald's theory). I wanted at least to be able to study hard the secretary problem and give a variation of my own. I came with the idea of studying a hypothetical growing group starting with n members. Principles are:

1. There's only a possible size of the group.
2. Maximum size is known.
3. Sizes are explored sequentially (as group grows) and all of them can equally likely be chosen (here is where I think I might fail).
4. It's possible to make a ranking between the sizes without ties. Decision of choosing any size is judged only by relative position in raking with prior sizes. In my case, I am ranking the sizes according to their objetivo function (see in code above)
5. Once a size is rejected (decision of continue growing is taken) it's not possible to go back to that size expelling people from the group.
6. Reward is 1 if best size is chosen and 0 otherwise.

In order to simulate that experience I modeled groups using graphs and I stablished the score of the group, which determines position in ranking, by the value of the objective function: arithmetic mean of cohesion and descentralization. As you can note, connections between members are stablished according to a simpathy distribution matrix whose values are uniformly distributed in [0,1]. I tried the look and leap formula, which isn't working because probability of success varies with no actual direction using different values of M, and to study the correlation between optimal size and max size but, even when I got statistical significancy, correlation was weak tough. I pressume that I cannot solve using the original stopping rule because of the distribution of sizes in the ranking as I set it, doesn't seem to be uniform.

I would appreciate some insight about the problem. If there's a light reconsideration so the problem adjusts to a given stopping rule or if anyone can help me find a stopping rule for this.

**EDIT**
I have been asked to edit this post so question is clear. Well, I am asking for help to:

1. Whether change my problem so it adjusts to the stopping rule the secretary problem does, because right now it does not and I theorize it is because of the ranking criteria (you can try to plot M vs probability using my code to observe this).
2. Or help me find a stopping rule optimal for my actual problem.

I emphasize my problem seems not to be the secretary problem just because the solution doesn't seem to work, according to my code. And I repeat that I guess it's because ranking according to function objetivo doesn't behave as uniform distribution among the group sizes.

I leave the Python code I used here:

```py
import random, sys
import numpy as np, networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd

def descentralizacion_grupo(matriz_grupo):
    conexiones_integrante = np.sum(matriz_grupo, axis=0)
    max_conexiones = np.max(conexiones_integrante)
    if max_conexiones == 0:
        return 0
    return np.mean([con/max_conexiones for con in conexiones_integrante])

def cohesion_grupo(matriz_grupo):
    tamaño_grupo = len(matriz_grupo)
    return np.sum(matriz_grupo) / (tamaño_grupo*tamaño_grupo)

# Define la posición relativa de los tamaños de grupos en el ranking
def objetivo_grupo(matriz_grupo):
    cohesion = cohesion_grupo(matriz_grupo)
    descentralizacion = descentralizacion_grupo(matriz_grupo)
    return 0.5*(cohesion+descentralizacion)

# Simulacion estrategia de coger a M-1 personas y quedarse con el primer grupo mejor a partir de la persona M. Siempre hay 100 candidatos
def simular_grupos(): 
    n_candidatos = 100
    M_range = range(5, 6+n_candidatos) #tamaño del grupo varía entre 5 y 105 personas
    niter = range(100)
    prob_result = [] # Probabilidad promedio de éxito en encontrar un grupo óptimo con la estrategia
    
    #simulamos para cada valor de M
    for M in M_range:
        result = np.full(len(niter),0)
        for s in niter:
            grupo = nx.Graph()
            print(M)
            simpatia = np.random.uniform(0,1,(5+n_candidatos, 5+n_candidatos)) # Establecemos la simpatia que tiene i por j como simpatia[i][j]
            #simpatia[range(5+n_candidatos),range(5+n_candidatos)]=1.0
            integrantes = list(range(M)) # Los integrantes iniciales del grupo son 0,...,M-1
            #print(f"Integrantes iniciales {integrantes}")
            grupo.add_nodes_from(integrantes)  # Se crea el grupo original
            objetivo = [0]*(n_candidatos+5)    # Lista para almacenar los objetivos

            
            for i in integrantes:
                conexiones = []
                azar = random.random() # Azar de que 'i' encaje en el grupo
                for j in integrantes:  # Pasa por el integrante 'j'
                    if azar < simpatia[i][j] and simpatia[j][i]: # Si 'i' y 'j' se llevan bien
                        conexiones.append((i,j)) # Se crea relación entre 'i' y 'j'
                grupo.add_edges_from(conexiones) # Actualizamos las conexiones en el grupo
                matriz_grupo = np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(grupo).todense())
                objetivo[i] = objetivo_grupo(matriz_grupo)
            mejor_objetivo = max(objetivo)  # Inicializamos el mejor objetivo con el máximo de los objetivos iniciales hasta M-1
            optimo = M-1

            # Simulamos la incorporacion de candidatos a partir de M
            acc = 0
            for i in range(M, n_candidatos+5): # Candidato 'i' a unirse al grupo
                conexiones = []
                azar = random.random() # Azar que determina si 'i' encaja en el grupo
                integrantes.append(i)
                for j in integrantes: # Pasamos por todos los integrantes
                    if simpatia[i][j] > azar and simpatia[j][i] > azar: #Si los integrantes se caen bien
                        conexiones.append((i,j)) # Se crea una relación entre los dos
                grupo.add_edges_from(conexiones) 
                matriz_grupo = np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(grupo).todense())  
                objetivo[i]=objetivo_grupo(matriz_grupo)
                if objetivo[i] > mejor_objetivo:
                    mejor_objetivo=objetivo[i]
                    if acc == 0:
                        optimo = i
                    acc += 1
            if optimo != M-1 and objetivo[optimo] == max(objetivo):
                result[s] = 1
        prob_result.append(np.mean(result))
    return prob_result
```

I am expecting to solve this problem using an optimal stopping rule or modify it lightly to be able to use some stopping rule.